# Till which device width size should I make web pages responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I made my webpages responsive but a horizontal bar appears when width is less than 350px, I found out that the navbar is crossing the boundary. Should I fix this? If yes how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smallest width you should make responsive code is 320px.

When you get horizontal scroll that means that you have either:

- Content which does not wrap
- Have elements with a `min-width` or an element with `min-width` bigger than the viewport
- Large margins/paddings squeezing your content
- Though the body has the width of the viewport something within  has a bigger width than the viewport
- An absolute positioned element or an element positioned outside of the viewport.

Some people usually use `body { overflow-x: hidden; }` to mitigate or prevent any horizontal scrolling. But I would advise against it as I prefer dealing with css/html problems rather hiding them.

Comment: totally agree on your overflow statement. Especially as many missing that overflow-hidden not preventing an overflow, just hiding the scrollbar and disabling scroll ability.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays normally the minimal responsive width is used to be 320px (i.e. width of the first iPhone SE).

You can use Chrome Developer Tools in mobile simulation mode, there are the predefined widths and accordingly the popular devices having this width.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the scroll bar, but if the responsiveness is good upto 320px then your good.